# How could I execute other commands while using registry keys in windows?

Tags: windows, shell, registry, regedit

I want to launch a software in Chrome, then I used an external protocol like this(in a .reg file):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ATS]
@="URL:ATS Protocol Handler"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ATS\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ATS\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ATS\shell\open\command]
@="D:\\ATS\\ATS.exe \"%1\""
```

But for some reasons, I need to get into the D:\ATS\ folder first, and then launch the ATS.exe program. I think I should add some commands like

```
cd d:\ATS
```

but how and where to write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the last line to

```
@="cd D:\\ATS & D:\\ATS\\ATS.exe \"%1\""
```

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work, neither does the code @="d: & cd ATS & D:\\ATS\\ATS.exe \"%1\""(works in Windows cmd)

Comment: Try `cmd /c cd /d d:\\ATS && d:\\ATS\\ATS.exe %1`